# Can not get internet

Tags: internet

my internet says the it's conected. But when I search anything it says 
this site can not be reached 
Ask ubuntu.com's server Ip address could not be found.

What should I do?

Comment: What exactly says you're connected? status lights on the modem and router may show you as connected, but that might only mean you are connected to the ISP and nothing is getting past their servers (literally just happened to me a couple days ago).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsb_release -d` and then also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Open your terminal and write:

```
cd /etc
sudo nano resolv.conf
#comment the line of nameserver 127.0.0.53 if it was found
#type:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
#then click ctrl + x to save, press y, press Enter
```

finally, write inside the terminal the following command to restart the network service:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: if you found the line nameserver 127.0.0.53(any number) comment it by typing before it a #

Comment: mean "#" a hash tag

Comment: before you do anything just try to restart your network service by the last command I wrote using terminal, if that did not fix the problem do the same steps I gave you upside

Comment: This will not survive a reboot is only a temporary band-aid.